# Νetwork setup with two subnets to serve a stream

Tags: networking, router, vpn, routing

My network has two routers.

The main router A is connected to the internet and defines the network 192.168.1.0/24.
The second router B connected with wan ip 192.168.1.4/24 to A and defines a separate network (192.168.10.0). This serves wifi and eth clients (esp32, arduino devices, etc) as a separate subnet.

On the subnet B there is a device in the static ip address 192.168.10.6 that I would like to be able to serve a stream to both networks (cam).

For this purpose:

- I have added a port forwarding (port 60 to 192.168.10.6:80) on the router B.
- On router A I have added route 192.168.10.0 to 192.168.1.4
- I have turned firewall off on router B

I think the current setup is reflected on the routing tables below also.

The issue is that the stream is not visible from subnet A. When I ask for Firefox (from subnet A) to look for the stream it can’t establish a connection to the server at 192.168.1.4:61 .

Pinging from subnet 192.168.10.0/24 to 192.168.1.0/24 works but not the other way around.

What am I missing. Any help is much appreciated! Thank you!

Edit (updated):

I issued tcpdump and also pinged and got the following (i did it from subnet A):

```
~ $ ping 192.168.10.6. 

PING 192.168.10.6 (192.168.10.6) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 192.168.1.4 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.1.4 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable


~ $ sudo tcpdump -e -v -n icmp

tcpdump: listening on eth0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes

11:00:41.766499 b8:27:eb:da:ce:18 > 00:25:9c:3c:35:fd, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 98: (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 49017, offset 0, flags [DF], proto ICMP (1), length 84)

192.168.1.84 > 192.168.10.6: ICMP echo request, id 27244, seq 1, length 64

11:00:42.809831 b8:27:eb:da:ce:18 > 00:25:9c:3c:35:fd, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 98: (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 49054, offset 0, flags [DF], proto ICMP (1), length 84)

192.168.1.84 > 192.168.10.6: ICMP echo request, id 27244, seq 2, length 64

11:00:43.849813 b8:27:eb:da:ce:18 > 00:25:9c:3c:35:fd, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 98: (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 49105, offset 0, flags [DF], proto ICMP (1), length 84)

192.168.1.84 > 192.168.10.6: ICMP echo request, id 27244, seq 3, length 64

11:00:44.764472 00:25:9c:3c:35:fd > b8:27:eb:da:ce:18, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 126: (tos 0xc0, ttl 64, id 44829, offset 0, flags [none], proto ICMP (1), length 112)

192.168.1.4 > 192.168.1.84: ICMP host 192.168.10.6 unreachable, length 92
        (tos 0x0, ttl 63, id 49017, offset 0, flags [DF], proto ICMP (1), length 84)

192.168.1.84 > 192.168.10.6: ICMP echo request, id 27244, seq 1, length 64

11:00:44.764631 00:25:9c:3c:35:fd > b8:27:eb:da:ce:18, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 126: (tos 0xc0, ttl 64, id 44830, offset 0, flags [none], proto ICMP (1), length 112)
```

If i use arp option without eth filter i get a lot of records to be put here. Do you have a hint as to what to look for?

Edit2: After I have done some more attempts to resolve the issue (I have reset to defaults and downloaded new firmware. I setup the router B as operating mode "router", disabled firewall and NAT, disabled the port forward for now.) I get the following:
[route and pinging results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mVOnf.png)

[my network](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wejiw.png)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/125044/discussion-on-question-by-thermike-etwork-setup-with-two-subnets-to-serve-a-str).

Answer (score 0):

After some discussion with you guys I realized that the problem was on the cam setup as by error the subnet mask was set to 255.255.0.0 and not 255.255.255.0
After correcting cam setup the stream routes normally to a firefox running on subnet A.
Thanks!